# Numpy Matrix Difference row by row into 3D tensor

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am looking for a fast way to compute a 3D `np.ndarray` such that given `X.shape == (m,p)` and `X2.shape == (n,p)`,

`tau[i,j] = X[i] - X2[j]`
with `tau.shape == (m,n,p)`

I have the following iterative (read, slow) method thus far:

```
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    for j in range(X2.shape[0]):
        tau[i,j] = X[i] - X2[j]
```

This works but I'd like to know if there is a faster way to do this using some broadcasting trick or something.

Thanks!

Comment: So, going by the linked dup question, here you would have : `X[:,None,:] - X2` or simply : `X[:,None]-X2`.

Comment: @Divakar thanks a bunch!!